# Regular expression - PCRE (PHP) - word boundary (\b) and accent characters

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, pcre, non-ascii-characters

Why does the letter `é` count as a word boundary matching `\b` in the following example?

Pattern: `/\b(cum)\b/i`

Text: `écumé`

Matches 'cum' which is not desired.

Is it possible to overcome this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will work, when you add the `u` modifier to your regex

```
/\b(cum)\b/iu
```

Comment: Thanks! Silly me, should have investigated modifiers a bit more.

Comment: Adding the Unicode modifier makes the regex treat input string as Unicode. PS: underrated question & solution.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with unicode, replace `\b` with

```
/(?<=^|\PL)(cum)(?=\PL|$)/i
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems too complex. stema's answer addresses the issue more straightforward, as the problem is that the text has unicode characters but the pattern is not made aware of this.